# Appium: Cannot use Inspector to record GUI steps of Android app on Windows 7

Tags: android, appium, windows

I'm trying to use Appium inspector for recording manual GUI steps. But, I'm not even getting the option like record or anything else when I start inspector.

**Note:** I'm capable of inspecting the elements with inspector.

Comment: can you share sc5reenshot of appium and appium version

Comment: @Keshav Appium version is 1.4.16.1. Screen shot is this [link](http://imgur.com/bBq6mVv). I'm not getting options other than options available on screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself after a couple of days. I'm updating the answer so it will be useful to the others.

As of now, appium inspector does not have option for record on Windows OS. But, the same option is available for MAC OS.